# Need to migrate an application from Blackfish to Firebird

Tags: database, delphi, firebird, data-migration, blackfish

What is the effort to migrate from Blackfish to Firebird ?

I use DBX4

No stored procedure, or function or views

I access all my data trough SQL queries

Comment: delphi 2007, but I will upgrade at the end of 2011, to what ever new version.

Comment: So DBX4 driver for firebird will be in the box (start with delphi 2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a driver for delphi and dbx4 firebird
http://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/

my guess is that is easy for you to dump the blackfish tables into csv
and then to import them in firebird and later modify only the application to access 
the firebird db using the dbx4 firebird settings

Comment: I just care about the code effort. The data migration I dont see any problems, cvs, or other method.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't rely on specific Blackfish features (SP, trigger, admin packages calls etc), the change should not be a pain.

I've did this kind of migration in a DEMO for a customer.

If you have used Blackfish as a "collection of tables accessible via SQL" then the change will not be difficult at all.

Answer (score 1):

For database pumping you can use tools like :

[IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.com) (full version)

[Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com) (full version)

or [database comparer](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/dbcomparer/index.asp)